# Java instanceof something softcoded?

Tags: java, instanceof

I have an enum called `PacketType`. Then I have a class called `Packet` and the class `DummyPacket` that extends `Packet`.

```java
public class Packet {
}

public class DummyPacket extends Packet {
    public void handle() {
    }
}
```

I want some sort of handler such that when I get some Object Packet I want to call the `handle()` method from -DummyPacket`. Is there some way to do this softcoded or do I have to do 
`Packet instanceof DummyPacket`
for every class that extends Packet?

I tried using `Class<?>.isInstance()`, but that didn't help me, because I couldn't get the `Class<?>` to call the method:

I sort of want to call it like this:

public static void handle(Packet packet) {
       if (packet.getType().clazz.isInstance(packet)) {
           packet.getType().clazz.handle();
       }
   }

Comment: "I tried using Class.isInstance(), but that didn't help me, Because I couldn't get the Class to call the method." Please show what you tried.

Comment: Do not *explain* what you do in your code. Show us your code instead.

Comment: `packet.getType().getClass()`?

Comment: But from there i can't call the handle method.

Comment: Is my answer not working for you? It looks like it's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes it would, but I don't only have 1 Class that extends the Packet and I would like to not have to check all of them one by one.

Comment: Ok, in that case, you would need an Interface. Let me show you by updating my answer.

Comment: Why not `instanceof`? Why even call the method for objects of type `Packet` and not filter beforehand? What does `PacketType` have to do with it?

Comment: In PacketType I saved the value I get from ```packet.getType()``` and then with ```.clazz``` I get the Class that should handle the Packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```java
public void callHandle(Packet packet) {
  if (packet instanceof DummyPacket) {
    ((DummyPacket) packet).handle();
  }
}
```

[EDIT] After the OP gave more information, it turns out that he is looking for a way to have multiple classes have a method with the same signature.

What you are looking for is interfaces. Take a look at these classes:

```
public class Packet { }
public interface Handleable {
  public void handle();
}

public class DummyPacket extends Packet implements Handleable {
  @Override
  public void handle() {
    // Do something
  }
}

public class OtherPacket extends Packet implements Handleable {
  @Override
  public void handle() {
    // Do something else
  }
}

public class LastPacket extends Packet { }
```

With this example, you have 3 classes that `extend` the `Packet` class:

- `DummyPacket`
- `OtherPacket`
- `LastPacket`

But only 2 classes that implement the `Handleable` interface:

- `DummyPacket`
- `OtherPacket`

This means that you can check if a class has the `handle` method like this:

```
public void callHandle(Handeable someClass) {
  someClass.handle();
}
```

Now, we can filter out all classes that do not have the `handle` method.

I suggest you read more about [inheritance](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp), [abstract classes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_abstraction.htm) and [interfaces](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp).